# MEAN full stack and SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, mean-stack

Does it make sense to change from MongoDB to SQL Server in the MEAN full stack (Node Express and Angular)?

Comment: Not saying it is a good idea or not but if you do it would no longer be the MEAN stack. :)

Comment: It would, actually, be a SEAN stack, @SeanLange.

Comment: @EricBrandt LOL

Comment: haha, thanks I'll take a look at the SEAN stack

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In today's data environment, the unfortunate truth is that there is no one "right" data appliance for all use cases. At my last job, we used Hadoop for our streaming data, Couchbase as a web data caching layer, Hive when we needed the illusion of a relational database, SQL Server on Azure when we needed a temporal data store with more than the illusion of relational characteristics, on prem SQL Servers when for the persistence layer where we needed actual relational data, and a Netezza cube for reporting. There's not a handy acronym for that hot mess.

I will say that a lot of shops that are primarily NoSQL focused like Postgres as an RDBMS addition since it keeps with the whole open source philosophy, but your mileage may vary.

The TLDR; answer to your question is that it depends on your use case(s), and there's no avoiding painful hours of research and probably a few false starts before you land on a solution that works for you.